# How to use JQuery to read / target an external svg file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

So I have an external SVG file. I connected this file on html via  code. My SVG ID is "external-svg"

```
<object id="SVGNAMEHERE"  data="link.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
        width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

As it is an external file, I understand that I have to allow document to load first and to call the file when trying to target its path in Jquery. Here's my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var svgObject = document.getElementById('SVGNAMEHERE').contentDocument;
      var svg = svgObject.getElementById('external-svg');
      console.log(svg);
    });
```

I am getting this error "cannot read property element get id of null"

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

Comment: None of that is jQuery. jQuery doesn't have the capability to cross document boundaries. I don't think you can access the content of an `object` element via javascript.

Comment: Do you know how I can cross document from SVG and Javascript? Been hunting for an answer but cant find any... My script only works when it's inline ugh

Comment: Possibly via `iframe` assuming you can meet CORS requirements (same domain, etc.).